# C++ function with different return types

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to write a function that takes a plane and a line in R^3 and returns their intersection. Obviously, I have to distinguish between three possible cases: i) the line intersects the plane in a single point, ii) the line is a subset of the plane, iii) the line is parallel to the plane (and not a subset of it). This results in three possible return types for the function.

I've been working a lot with OCaml recently, which would allow me to distinguish between these different types very explicitly by returning a variant type from my function. How do people deal with this kind of issue in C++?

One idea that comes to mind is to use a tuple of {bool, bool, vector} as my return type, where the first boolean says whether the line and the plane have a non-empty intersection, the second boolean says whether they intersect in a single point if the first boolean is true (and is meaningless otherwise), and the vector returns the unique intersection if both booleans are true (and is meaningless otherwise). However, this feels very inelegant and hacky, I have to inform users of the function of the meaning of the tuple entries using comments, I return variables which can be meaningless, etc.

What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Using a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is one option and maybe the best one, but if that return type is something you're going to return consistently it's probably best to give it a formal name or `typedef`.

Comment: Why not use a `struct`?  This way you can have named return arguments.

Comment: Why, return a [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) type from your function of course

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question? It's clear, concise, and shows effort.  Tarvoc, don't worry too much about the downvotes and welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @n.m. using a variant means that client code has to know somehow what it should expect in the returned value. with a class/struct return type, such the one proposed in Jonathan Olson ansewer, or something else if needed, people using that code can understand the result of the method just looking at the names of variable/methods available in the returned class

Comment: It'll be hard for someone to answer without having more detail about your formats provided.  For example one way to approach the problem would be to use the same data type for all planes, lines, etc., with member values set according to what is being represented.  Another way is to do what Eigen does, and there are various stages in between

Comment: @GianPaolo Sorry I don't quite understand your point. Why woult looking at `std::variant<Line,Point,Nothing>` prove more confusing than looking at `struct linePlaneIntersect`?

Comment: std::variant is also C++17, so there's not great support and you need the latest tools. Try suggesting that to someone with GCC < v8 or VS < 2017 and you'll get another question in 15 minutes about why it doesn't compile

Comment: @JonathanOlson The question is about C++. The current standard is C++17. If you have problems because of poor choice of tools by your management, ask how to cope. Inventing a special kind of barely fitting tagged union for each task is **not** a solution.

Comment: @n.m. Ouch. I run a C++11 shop: we'll probably port to C++17 in the mid 20s. Personally I think C++11 is the default standard in SO. Perhaps I'm getting old.

Comment: @Bathsheba for such poor souls, `boost` is usually able to provide a workaround. Or one could write their own replacement of std::variant in C++11. It's not that hard, and will serve you... I dunno, probably until the mid 20s.

Comment: @n.m. "Poor choice of tools by your management" Expecting C++11 is reasonable, expecting C++17 with no disclaimer is unreasonable. Scenarios! Non professionals using what's available, people writing embedded code with tools that don't support the latest and greatest, people building against closed source binaries built with a particular toolset...the list goes on. An answer requiring C++17 is fine, but now you're just being toxic.

Comment: @n.m I hope so. I'm looking forward to `std::optional` (yes, I use the one in `boost` and we are wedded to `boost` by virtue of their excellent date library and boost::spirit), and being able to write `namespace A::B`. But I can't really justify the move to C++17 right now. C++11 was a quantum leap forward over C++03 but I'm not sure what real benefits C++17 has. Shall I get me coat?

Comment: @JonathanOlson I understand that not everyone can use C++17 or boost because of this or that, but I can't do much about it. These tools were invented to provide good solutions for existing problems. If you can't use them, it stands for a reason that you *might possibly* have to use an inferior solution. Nothing wrong with that, but this unconditional "it's bad because it's C++17 and I can't use C++17" stance leads to nowhere. Perhaps "C++17 might have a good solution, let's see what we can steal from it without switching to C++17" would be a tad more productive.

Comment: @Bathsheba 17 is nice to work with because it has a lot of small improvements. Incidentally I had a conversation about C++17 at work today. Inline variables, new template argument deduction, variant and optional are very important features for several of my colleagues.

Comment: @Bathsheba For non library writers, the best is probably structured bindings. Think nested associative containers.

Comment: @n.m. pointing out that a solution requires C++17 (which the majority of people don't work with) is not unproductive. It's not bad because it's C++17, it's a good answer, and I already upvoted your answer below.

Comment: @n.m you are right, my mistake. I was confusing `std::variant` with a Variant in VB, wich is more or less something similar to `std::any`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are several *generic* (i.e. not limited to geometrical lines and points) ways to cope with the problem.

1. `std::variant` (or its older sibling `boost::variant` for those who cannot run C++17).
2. Plain old union (tagged):

   ```
   struct LinePlaneIntersection {
     enum { IsLine, IsPlane } intersection_type;
     union {
        Point p;
        Line l;
     };
   };
   ```

   If `Point` and `Line` have not-trivial constructors and/or destructors, you'd need to add ctors and dtors to the above scheme.
3. Plain old inheritance.

   ```
   class LinePlaneIntersection { ... };
   class NoIntersection : public LinePlaneIntersection { ... };
   class OnePointIntersection : public LinePlaneIntersection { ... };
   class OneLineIntersection : public LinePlaneIntersection { ... };
   ```

   Return a `LinePlaneIntersection*` (or better and much preferable `std::unique_ptr<LinePlaneIntersection>`) from your function. Then there's of course the problem of what to do with the returned value. You may want to use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) here.
4. Continuation passing. Don't return anything, accept a continuation instead. In this case, three continuations:

   ```
   void intersect (Line line, Plane plane,
                   std::function<void(Line)> onLine,
                   std::function<void(Point)> onPoint,
                   std::function<void()> onNothing);
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like:

```
struct Point3D
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Line
{
    Point3D p1;
    Point3D p2;
};

struct Plan {
    Point3D p;
    Point3D orthogonalDir;
};

std::optional<std::variant<Point3D, Line>>
ComputeIntersection(const Line& line, const Plan& plan);
```

Comment: You missed a z coordinate btw.

Answer (score 1):

Why not return a struct with an enum type? Someone using the function could then first check the type of intersection before attempting to use the data.

```
enum IntersectType {
    INTERSECTION_NONE,
    INTERSECTION_POINT,
    INTERSECTION_LINE,
};

struct Point3D {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}

struct LinePlaneIntersect {
    IntersectType type;
    std::vector<Point3D> intersect; //since you mentioned vector
};

//Check within another function
struct LinePlaneIntersect intersection = fun(line, plane);

if (intersection.type == INTERSECTION_POINT) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of a solution along the same lines. I have a feeling the OP wants to return a geometric vector, not the C++ type.

Comment: true about the vector type, but is there a difference? vector type also allows passing 0 3D points for no intersect, 1 point for point intersect, and two points for line intersects

Comment: They want to return the point of intersection only when the intersection is of type `INTERSECTION_POINT`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to shoehorn different types of geometry into a vector of doubles. It may work for a line and a point, but it doesn't generalise well. What if you intersect a curve and a plane? two 3D surfaces? two N-dimensional manifolds? You need to invent a new type of solution for each of these problems.

Comment: And? he asked about a line and a plane. I don't need to jump start the singularity to answer his question. Besides, almost every geometry imaginable can be represented with a list of points.

Comment: @n.m. we're not going to invent a complete tensor library in a SO answer

Comment: @M.M IRL if you follow the path outlined in this answer, you **will** have to invent a complete tensor library at some point. The conclusion is that this path leads to a dead end. It may or may not be OK depending on where you want to arrive eventually. It is my impression that OP would rather go elsewhere, because the problem is stated in a generic way. Not "I have a problem of returning either a line or a point from a function", but "I want to return different type from a function, and here's an example with a line and a point". But of course you are free to look at it however you want.

Comment: Modified my answer to use another struct, Point3D instead of just a vector of doubles to make cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are nice new shiny ways of dealing with this (`std::tuple`, `std::variant`, &c.), the tried-and-tested way is to design a `class` (or even a set of related classes) that can represent the various states and return an instance of that.

It's this approach that always seems to *scale* up best as your project evolves. So much so, that the committee behind Java has never emitted a tuple or a variant type into their language and libraries.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting that the return type is a class instance? With the class having either a member variable or yet another function to query what type the intersection is?

Comment: @JonathanOlson: I am indeed suggesting that, and indeed possibly with yet another function. Perhaps even some kind of double dispatch mechanism in the long term.

Comment: If that's the case, could you flesh out your answer? OP seems fairly new and in need of more detailed guidance.

Comment: @JonathanOlson: I think it's best to leave it here. A comment above: "we're not going to invent a complete tensor library in a SO answer" applies here too.

Comment: It's reasonable to not write example code, but a basic description beyond "return a class" is necessary. I.e. my comment, based on the level of the question suggesting a member variable or member function to indicate the intersection type goes a long way toward understanding why you might use a class. I edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: @JonathanOlson: Genuinely I believe I can't add to this without inventing things that really out to belong to the question. There's not harm in editing your answer though to incorporate the concepts above; hopefully in a better way.

Comment: Guess the edit needs to be peer reviewed to be accepted